# Use string to select array

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview, android-activity

Trying to take an Array position(toString) and pass that to a new activity, then use that string to select which array to open in the new activity.

```
Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
String content = launchingIntent.getData().toString();
setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.????, R.layout.main)); `
```

the R.array.???? needs to be the string that is passed (string content), because that is the name of my array to follow up with.

I can't find a way to pass the string variable to the name of the array to use.

EDIT: Im trying to get one listView to open up another Listview in the same actvity, closing the prior one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the R.array.???? needs to be the string that is passed (string
>   content), because that is the name of my array to follow up with.

Use the [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();
String content = launchingIntent.getData().toString(); // this returns the Uri, are you sure you didn't want to get the text from an extra field set in the Intent
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(content, "array", getPackageName());
setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), id, R.layout.main));
```

> Im trying to get one listView to open up another Listview in the same
>   actvity, closing the prior one.

I would advise against this because you lose the back button functionality(which may confuse the user). Instead use different activities passing relevant data with `Intents` or use fragments(especially `ListFragments`).

Comment: so having multiple (say 20+) classes isn't going to bog my app down then?

Comment: @IamERROR You shouldn't use an activity for each entry in the first `ListView`(this is what you want to do?). Instead create two activities, one with the initial `ListView` and the other a "details ListView" which uses the information from the previous activity to setup its UI.